# Angular Selectize - Bind to Model (not Value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selectize.js

I'm using the [angular-selectize plugin](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize). I can't see how to get the whole of the object as the selected item and not just the value.

Please see this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eONcjb?p=preview)

For Example:
Instead of getting "1000" as the Selected Item I'd like to get:

```
{
    "value": "1000",
    "name": "LONDON",
    "longitude": "-0.14922",
    "latitude": "51.49267",
    "class": "Your Most Searched"
}
```

I'm sure this is trivial, but I can't see how to do it through my `ng-model` attribute.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: provide link to docs, should be configurable or provide events access

Comment: Documents are [here](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md). I can't see anything (I'd ideally achieve it without using a custom callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue that has already been raised as an issue on the GitHub repository, [see here](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize/issues/57)

As of yet there is no way of doing this out of the box, the suggested workaround which I was trying to avoid is to have the model referencing the key. I'd then need to use Lodash or Underscore to search the array for the whole object.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, it was always when onChange is triggered, I take the key and run a micro-service that searches for the last data in the preloaded collection, or in some cases, I look in the API.

It's more work, though, it works fine.